Can we change an HTML to see older versions of the page
I am using this page https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=1410028703 and I need to get all versions of this page from January 2019 to September 2024. However, this page forces you to look at each link individually.
Doing some digging, I see that you can go back to individual pages, but you have to adjust the hyperlink, e.g (look at the referenceperiods=).

August 2024: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=1410028703&pickMembers%5B0%5D=3.1&pickMembers%5B1%5D=4.1&cubeTimeFrame.startMonth=08&cubeTimeFrame.startYear=2024&referencePeriods=20240801%2C20240801
July 2024: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=1410028703&pickMembers%5B0%5D=3.1&pickMembers%5B1%5D=4.1&cubeTimeFrame.startMonth=07&cubeTimeFrame.startYear=2024&referencePeriods=20240701%2C20240701

I was wondering if its possible to do this using the following strategy:

Make a vector of hyperlinks corresponding to the period of Jan-2019 to Sept-2024 by changing the hyperlink endings
Use the download.file() function in R to download (temporary files) each element in this vector
Once everything is downloaded, vertically stack them together

Could I do it this way? Or is there some other way to do this on the website itself?
Note: Actual Link Format for download: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/dtl!downloadDbLoadingData-nonTraduit.action?pid=1410028703&latestN=0&startDate=20240801&endDate=20240801&csvLocale=en&selectedMembers=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B1%5D%5D&checkedLevels=

Here is my current script - there has to be an easier way than this, yes?:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)

generate_urls <- function(start_date, end_date) {
    dates <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "month")
    
    urls <- map_chr(dates, function(date) {
        start_date <- format(date, "%Y%m01")
        end_date <- format(date, "%Y%m01")
        
        paste0(
            "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/dtl!downloadDbLoadingData-nonTraduit.action?pid=1410028703",
            "&latestN=0",
            "&startDate=", start_date,
            "&endDate=", end_date,
            "&csvLocale=en",
            "&selectedMembers=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%5D%2C",
            "%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B1%5D%5D",
            "&checkedLevels="
        )
    })
    
    return(urls)
}

urls <- generate_urls(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2024-09-01"))

download_and_process <- function(url) {
    temp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
    download.file(url, temp_file, mode = "wb")
    
    data <- read_csv(temp_file, skip = 0) %>%
        mutate(Date = ymd(REF_DATE))
    
    unlink(temp_file)
    return(data)
}

all_data <- map_dfr(urls, download_and_process)

write_csv(all_data, "combined_statcan_data.csv")


Download options > CSV Download entire table  /  https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/tbl/csv/14100287-eng.zip .  Description ( "Labour force characteristics, monthly, seasonally adjusted and trend-cycle, last 5 months") seems bit misleading, but it certainly includes records for 1976-01 .. 2024-09

This still not optimal, the statcanR package function statcan_download_data() downloads the full table of a dataset to CSV using its product ID. Based on the link you provided in your question, the product ID/table number for labour force characteristics is 14-10-0287-03. From there, we can filter the data to our date range of interest and export the results.
# devtools::install_github("warint/statcanR")

library(statcanR)
library(dplyr)

mydata <- statcan_download_data("14-10-0287-03", "eng") |>
  filter(
    between(
      REF_DATE,
      as.Date("2019-01-01"), # From Jan 2019
      as.Date("2024-09-01")  # To Sept 2024
    )
  )

write_csv(mydata, "statcan_data.csv")

Further optimization requires reading the web developers guide at Statistics Canada's website to write a custom function that leverages the SDMX REST APIs that power everything under the hood. Hope this helps!
